# Magento 2: Module Execution Preference

Tags: module, magento2.2.2

**I have 2 custom extensions overriding the same page**, i want to know,  **which extension will execute first and how?**

Answer (score 2):

All config files merged in order of modules are loaded. However You can change order by adding sequence in you module.xml file(s).

For example, in your case

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Module_1"/>
</sequence>
```

means that your current module will load after Module_1 and you will overwrite preferences of Module_1 modules